# Wrong play video after trimmed with ffmpeg

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, video-editing, ffprobe

After I cut a video with ffmpeg
HTML5 video is not displayed video I trim
this is the source code

```
<?php exec("ffmpeg.exe"); 
unlink("../output/dir/cut1.mp4");
clearstatcache();
exec("ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i ../input/1.mp4 -to 00:03:00 -c copy ../output/dir/cut1.mp4");
?>
<video width="300" height="auto" controls>
<source src="../output/dir/cut1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

result :
[Result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcz31.jpg)

```
exec("ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i ../input/1.mp4 -to 00:05:00 -c copy ../output/dir/cut1.mp4");
```

result :

[Result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TZ2S.jpg)

i must open the new tab to get the new duration from video i've trimmed
i can't get the new duration in the same tab even i've refreshed it
how come ?

Comment: you need to post all the code that you have tried; edit your question and hit CTRL + M and put all of your code into the box

Comment: thx @mlegg for your suggestion :)